# Using field reference in UDP in IIB

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I am setting reference to a field as a value to an UDP. [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/helYn.png). I wanted to reference the value at this path at runtime. Tried fetching the value using '{}' but seems like '{}' can't resolve path given in dots.
Second time tried fetching value using Eval function. Got stuck here too as Eval is throwing exception if my input has odd number of characters [see error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX6hZ.png) 
SET chrValue  = EVAL(LocalTxnID);
Please resolve on how to read the input which is a reference in UDP at runtime. Why are the above methods not working

Answer (score 0):

Looks as if these UDP values are for logging code. I see 'Global transaction id', 'Parent transaction id' and 'Local transaction id'. But IIB has built-in facilities for publishing messages with these fields (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac37860_.html). Is there a reason why you are not using those features?

> Tried fetching the value using '{}' but seems like '{}' can't resolve path given in dots.

Correct. The {} syntax applies to a single NameExpression. You cannot use it to navigate multiple path segments.

> Eval is throwing exception if my input has odd number of characters

The exception is reporting an invalid BLOB literal. That seems like a very strange error for an EVAL. Please check that you have quoted the correct error, and please also supply the exact string that EVAL received (if necessary take a user trace using mqsichangetrace, mqsireadlog, mqsiformatlog).